# Expressjs 4: Browser's POST request Returns Cannot GET / ... status of 404

Tags: post, http-status-code-404, nunjucks, express-handlebars, express-4

I just tried the following express 4 app, that simply sends a selected fruit from client to server and server suppose to respond back the name of the fruit. I got this example from [here](http://post_express_568d156ed8ca39082fd6eb2a.zip). The original example uses the template engine nunjucks by Mozilla. However, I adopted it to express-handlebars.

```
// app.js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    engines = require('consolidate'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        exphbs = require('express-handlebars');


    // view engine setup
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'main', layoutDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/'}));
app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

//app.engine('html', engines.nunjucks);
//app.set('view engine', 'html');
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

// Handler for internal server errors
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).render('error_template', { error: err });
}
app.use(errorHandler);

app.post('/favorite_fruit', function(req, res, next) {
//    res.redirect('/favorite_fruit');
    var favorite = req.body.fruit;
    console.log(favorite);
    if (typeof favorite == 'undefined') {
        next('Please choose a fruit!');
    }
    else {
        res.send("Your favorite fruit is " + favorite);
    }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('fruitPicker', { 'fruits' : [ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'peach' ] });
});





var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Express server listening on port %s.', port);
});
```

Here is my

```
<!--views/fruitPicker.hbs-->
<form action='/favorite_fruit' mehtod='POST'>

        <p>What is your favorite fruit?</p>
        {{#each fruits}}
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="fruit" value="{{this}}"/>{{this}}
        </p>
        {{/each}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My views/layouts/main.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

When I go to localhost:3000, it shows the form, but when I click on the submit button, it takes me to another page that says:

> Cannot GET /favorite_fruit?fruit=orange

I have [seen videos](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/handle-get-post-request-express-4/) they fix this using a click handler on the submit button using ajax. But in the example with nunjucks, there is not need to attach a click handler on the form's submit button. I don's see why I need this with if I use express-handlebars. Is there an issue with my code. Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: GET vs POST??  Hint, `mehtod='POST'` check your spelling...

Comment: Silly! I need to find out how to turn on automatic spell checking in my IDE! Thank you very much.

Comment: The key thing to see here was that you set up a POST request route, but your submits were registering as a GET request. When you ask yourself why that is, the spelling error jumps out at you.

Comment: zipzit, Thank you.

Comment: Now my question is can Testing with as chai and mocha can catch this? I guess I need to invest more time on that! Hopefully it pays off in the long run.